# Ajax load page without refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

I am looking for information what is the simplest way to update page content using jquery + ajax. I would like to update only `#container` content, but not a full page.

I am begginer in ajax.

Thanks.

MY Jquery code

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //page
      $('.row').load('services.html');

      $('.nav_link').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.row').load(page);
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
          <nav role="navigation" class="nav">
            <a class="nav_link" href="services"><div class="nav_line"></div>PASLAUGOS</a> <a class="nav_link" href="contacts.html"><div class="nav_line"></div>KONTAKTAI</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

services.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <nav role="navigation" class="nav">
        <a class="nav_link" href="services.html">
            <div class="nav_line"></div>
            PASLAUGOS
        </a> 
        <a class="nav_link" href="contacts.html">
            <div class="nav_line"></div>
            KONTAKTAI
        </a>
    </nav>
    <div class="result">
      gsdgdsgsdgdsgds gds gdsg dsg sd gds g sdgsd gdsg sd gsd
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ^^ Dude, as i see you do not understand my question. Load method refresh all my page...

Comment: Look at my updated post.

Comment: Much better. Try `$('.row').on("click",".nav_link",function(e){ e.preventDefault();var page = $(this).attr('href'); $('.row').load(page);});`

Comment: Oh Thanks. I'm surprised :O Thanks thanks thanks.

Could you explain what you have changed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
$('.row').on("click",".nav_link",function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
  var page = $(this).attr('href');   
  $('.row').load(page);
});
```

Since .on will assign the click to the new links

Comment: Is there any alternative for  $('.row').load(page);? I need to open new page in the whole of window, i mean i dont want to open it into an element, i want to replace all current page with another one, is that possible?

Comment: `location.href=page`

Comment: Great, thank you. Just look, my reason of doing that is making a "back button", So I need to select the whole content of current page *(even `<head>` tag)* and keep it into a JS array to use it when user clicks on "back button". Anyway, can you please tell me how can I select the whole things of current page?

Comment: Please ask a question instead of hijacking this one :) It is not really related

Comment: [well my friend did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330813/how-can-i-create-a-back-forward-button).. If you have some free time, please take a look at it :)