# Keep connected users through website pages using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have admin page with active users list. It works but when "userX" change to another page all clients are updated having no "userX" in active users list. Before 1 secound  "userX" returns to active users list.

**SERVER CONSOLE**

```
UserX connected...
UserX disconnected... (UserX change to another page inside application)
Reason: transport close
UserX connected... (Because main layout force connection)
```

When "userX" change to another page nodejs fires ***socket.on('disconnect',function(){})*** action.
This causes **Client disconnected... (UserX change to another page inside application)
Reason: transport close**

**SERVER CODE**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(81, function () {
    console.log('NodeJs listening on port:81');
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('New client connected...');

    socket.on('disconnect', function (reason) {
        console.log('Client disconnected...');
        console.log('Reason: ' + reason);
    });

});
```

***PAGE CODE***

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket = io(':81', {forceNew: true});
 </script>
```

How to keep user connected between pages and fire **disconnect** only when browser get closed or user get logging out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using page redirect for change the page then page will be refreshed.And every time when page got refreshed the socket will disconnect.

For that, you have to use `internal routing` to `load another page`.

Check this answer
[Ajax load page without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980021/ajax-load-page-without-refresh)